# What is "Session Storage" in Chrome Developer Tools?

Tags: google-chrome, session

What is *Session Storage* under the *Resources* tab of *Chrome's Developer Tools*?

Sessions are a server-side feature and cannot be accessed from the front end.

One can use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> shortcut to access the Developer Tools.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Guess its too late to answer but for anyone else, the session storage that is shown in chrome dev tools is [HTML5 sessionStorage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp#:%7E:text=Try%20it%20Yourself%20%C2%BB-,The%20sessionStorage%20Object,-The%20sessionStorage%20object) and not the server side Session.

Comment: The referenced page starts out with localStorage - sessionStorage is documented lower on the page.  See Dominic Watson's answer.

Comment: I fixed the link. 

Answer (score 7):

For Chrome, version 59x, you go to the Applications tab in Chrome Developer Tools.  It's for variables you can put into the client side javascript to persist it in that users session.  I use it with Angularjs as in:

```
$window.sessionStorage.setItem("username", $scope.userLogin.username);
```

See the picture below:

[image]

Comment: note you can access it through the Chrome Dev Tools JS console too if you want to interact with it