# With Django, not seeing request.session in Google Chrome Developer Tools?

Tags: django, session, session-variables, session-cookies

I'm trying to follow https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/sessions/#using-sessions-in-views to add session data to a request. I have subclass of Django's generic `ListView` in which the `get` method is overridden similar to the following:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    request.session['foo'] = 'bar'
    return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

I would expect that after accessing the page and going to Application -> Session Data, I would see the session data. However, I don't see anything:

[image]

Is saving session data supposed to work like this? The session engine is set to use signed cookies:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to see the session cookie in the `Cookies` section of the developer tools. Session storage [is something different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20170381/what-is-session-storage-in-chrome-developer-tools).